# Explicit to Recursive Formula

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I've spent the day trying to figure out how to make this particular explicit formula recursive, and come up empty.

$v(t)=(0.98^t-1)\times3.92$

None of my searches helped me in converting this type of equation, that or I wasn't able to connect the dots. So could someone show me how to make this formula recursive, or at least show me how to do it myself?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{v(t+1)+3.92}{v(t) + 3.92} = \;?$

Comment: @achillehui I'm sorry to bother you but it's been a week with no more answers and I still can't understand your hint. Could I get more of an explanation please?